# how to detect who is speaking

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, sapi

I'm developing a project for our workplace to manipulate with our environment like lights,coffee machine, printers and such, and I wan't to know how it would be possible to detect who is speaking to our system.

I'm building project with C# using `Speech.Recognition` library.

So far, I've managed to capture commands and execute simple things, but I want to go further and detect the person, so if a person for example "John" is speaking, then when he says "Hi system", the system logs the person speaking and responds "Hi John!" and after that it recognizes only "John's" voice commands and ignores different voices.

Comment: If I were doing it, I would probably build a library of 'usernames' so the person would say their name and it would compare it to a list of users, and then focus only on that user's speech patterns

Comment: Don't forget to add some sort of time-out so that others can use it when "john" is done.

Comment: @wjhguitarman problem with your solution is that anyone can say "John" and if I start implementing more serious workplace solutions I want to know exactly who was speaking.

Comment: As @sircapsalot answered, ideally it would match their voice pitch, speed, etc. to a matched identifier for John, so anyone else saying John would not trigger a match, and he could finish by using a key-phrase such as "End-Session" or some other identifier that would not be commonly spoken so as to trigger unwanted sign-outs.

Comment: @wjhguitarman so I have to analyze the audio sample that comes in, or is it built in somewhere?

Comment: You can check out a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263243/peak-frequencies-from-wav-file) as well.

Comment: @skmasq did you get your desired? I am working on a project like yours.

Comment: @AbdulMuheet hi there, sorry to disappoint, but we just went with simple speech recognition and didn't bother detecting who's talking.

Comment: its ok! I am trying my own

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is called `Voice Biometrics` and this is a difficult problem, solved by companies like Nuance (http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-solution/customer-service-solutions/solutions-services/inbound-solutions/voice-authentication-biometrics/index.htm). I'm sure there are open source / research solutions though.

A good project (in Java) for instance:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/marf/

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for voice identification or voice verification, which is one of the many uses of voice analysis. Beware, **voice identification is far from perfect**.

You would first need training data and algorithms, from which you would deduce statistical models for your speaker. Later, in the recognition/verification phase, you would try to fit input data against your statistical models and determine the threshold, which decides if the speaker is known or not. Some keywords if you would go about implementing this by yourself or just looking for more technical info are **Mel frequency cepstral coefficients, Gaussian mixture models and Hidden markov models**.

An interesting tool might be **[Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/)**. It's not available as library directly, but people at ICSI have written a wrapper called [praatlib](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/icsi/groups/speech/software). It extracts speech features such as **formant frequency, pitch**, and some more. ICSI used it for distinguishing between speakers within a recording (this is called diarization).

There are quite some free tools available, but all require an in-depth understanding of statistics, speech analysis and extensive amount of time in order to understand typically underdocumented academic code. Some interesting projects you should take a look at are **[Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) (Java) and [SHoUT](http://shout-toolkit.sourceforge.net/) (C++)**. Sphinx has good documentation, and SHoUT has a dissertation you can read if you find yourself questioning theoretical details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each user unique.

You can do this by having a pool of users, and using your recog library... store their unique voice attributes (pitch, level, etc) to said pool, then have your software recognize the attributes, and execute accordingly.

Comment: I'm checking into this right now, do you know any source where something like this is attempted?